# Improvement upon a for-loop: create a series of subsets without looping

Tags: r, for-loop, time-series, subset

My objective is to create a number of time-series subsets from a list of variables. I wrote this with a for-loop. However, I'm looking for more elegant ideas on how to do with an existir R function, that doesn't require a loop. 
All ideas and intros to new functions in R are much appreciated.

A reproducible example of the code:

```
russell_sim <- arima.sim(model=list(ar=c(.9,-.2)),n=449)
russell_sim <- ts(russell_sim, start = c(1980,1), end = c(2017,5) ,frequency = 12)

pmi_sim <- arima.sim(model=list(ar=c(.9,-.2)),n=449)
pmi_sim <- ts(russell_sim, start = c(1980,1), end = c(2017,5) ,frequency = 12)

big_list<- list(russell = russell_sim, pmi= pmi_sim) 

for (i in 1: length(big_list)) { 
  assign(paste(names(x = big_list)[i], "_before08", sep = ""), window(big_list[[i]], start=c(1981,1), end=c(2007, 12))  )
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the handy `list2env` function but you will need to edit the list first to get your desired output:

```
# New List to edit
big_list_before08 <- big_list
# change your observations
big_list_before08 <- lapply(big_list_before08, function(x) window(x, start = c(1981,1), 
                                                                     end = c(2007,12)))
# change the individual list element names
names(big_list_before08) <- paste0(names(big_list),"_before08")

# save to the global environment
list2env(big_list_before08, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Thanks, this works and it is exactly what I was looking for. One thing, why is it recommended to use lapply/list2env instead of looping in R? What are the advantages? Thank you.

Comment: Well, performance aside, the code is often cleaner, lapply will not add objects to your environment like a for loop will (the iterating term `i` for example), and you know the output will be in a list format. The for loop is better to use if you are iterating and reassigning the same object as you go or working with many different objects. Some people claim apply functions are faster than for loops but this is all contextual. I was just providing you an alternative to your current code, I find myself using the `assign` or `get` functions here and there :)